# C# Regex "Verbose" like in Python

Tags: c#, python, regex

In Python, we have the `re.VERBOSE` argument that allows us to nicely format `regex` expressions and include comments, such as

```
import re

ric_index = re.compile(r'''(
    ^(?P<delim>\.)    # delimiter "."
    (?P<root>\w+)$    # Root Symbol, at least 1 character
    )''',re.VERBOSE)
```

Is there something similar in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use verbatim string (using `@`), which allow you to write:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^(?<delim>\\.)     # delimiter "".""
                    (?<root>\\w+)$    # Root Symbol, at least 1 character
                    ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Note the use of [`RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) option to write verbose regexes.

Comment: Thomas, [this does not compile](https://ideone.com/wpITyn). Actually, your pattern is not a valid .NET pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my bad, now it does. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can have comments in .NET regex.

(examples copied from : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#miscellaneous_constructs)

You can have inline comments with `(?# .... )` :

```
string regex = @"\bA(?#Matches words starting with A)\w+\b"
```

or comment to the end of line `#`

```
string regex = @"(?x)\bA\w+\b#Matches words starting with A"
```

And you can always span your regex string on several lines, and use classic C# comments :

```
string regex = 
    @"\d{1,3}" +        // 1 to 3 digits
    @"\w+" +            // any word characters
    @"\d{10}";          // 10 digits
```

See also Thomas Ayoub's answer for use of verbatim string `@""` on several lines

Comment: *Not sure is you can get something as nicely layed out as in Python, though.* Sure it can. You already used a verbatim string literal in your answer, why not format it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'd completely forgotten that you could span a `@""` verbatim string on several lines C# :-O . thanks for the tip.

Comment: but actually you need to care with the whitespace in the beginning of lines. EDIT:  or use `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` as Thomas Ayoub mentionned in his answer.

Comment: Actually, `(?x)` is an inline `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` modifier, it provides the same functionality. I'd also add that literal `#` should be escaped in the meaningful parts of the patterns when using this modifier.